# How do you determine the time taken for a change in acceleration?

Tags: acceleration

It comes up constantly in pop-science. You need it to determine what would happen if Superman tried to punch the Hulk, and you need it to determine the life-saving effects of your seatbelts, airbags, and crumple zones. It's critically important in basic physics calculations.... and yet, I've never seen anybody go into how it's determined. A throwaway number is used. Usually a seemingly arbitrary value of .1 seconds or .001 seconds.

The time it takes for an object to change it's speed. If it's too fast, bad things happen. How do you determine how long this change takes?

Comment: This is a super vague question. If you have an ion drive on a spaceship it will take a very long time to change your speed. If you're in a car crash it will take a very short time to change your speed. That's about all you can say without a specific scenario.

Comment: VTC.  As Neurofuzzy says, its very vague. Sorry

Comment: *"How do you determine the time taken for a change in acceleration?"* and *"The time it takes for an object to change it's speed."* These are two different questions - two different parameters, we are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

The time $\Delta t$ very much depends on the circumstance.
Bad things is usually equivalent to too large a force acting on a person.
This force then causes breakage, injury, death etc so to prevent this the force has to be kept below a certain maximum value $F_{\rm max}$.

The force arises because to change the speed of the person $\Delta v$ the momentum (mass $\times$ velocity) has to change  $m\Delta v$.

According to Newton's second law force is the rate of change of momentum $F= \dfrac{m\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ where $\Delta t$ is the time over which the change in speed takes place.

So $\dfrac{m\Delta v}{\Delta t} < F_{\rm max}$ or $\Delta t > \dfrac{m\Delta v}{F_{\rm max}}$.

In reality this will under estimate the time because the slowing down process will not be constant and so the force may peak during the slowing down.

There is a whole section about seat belts on the [HyperPhysics website](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/carcr2.html) where you will note that the distance travelled during an impact is related to the time of impact.

Comment: In a car specific example, I imagine figuring out the peak might be something you could find out by looking at the stress/strength curve of the metal. Though ultimately it's always going to be different in the real world.

Comment: @SpaceOstrich You get an idea of a force vs time graph here http://auto.howstuffworks.com/car-driving-safety/accidents-hazardous-conditions/crash-test1.htm